# Changing UIToolbar Items Causes Toolbar to Go Blank

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a custom UIToolbar created in Storyboard containing rewind, pause, and fast-forward UIBarButtonItems. I am attempting to replace the pause button with a play button when clicked. My code is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomToolbar: UIToolbar!

@IBAction func playPause() {
    var newButton: UIBarButtonItem
    if !self.timer.valid {
        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        newButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "playPause")
    }
    else {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        newButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playPause")
    }
    var items = self.bottomToolbar.items
    items?[3] = newButton
    self.bottomToolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
}
```

The toolbar is initialized with a dark gray background with white buttons. However, after the attempted button switch, the entire toolbar goes white. Any ideas?

UPDATE 1:
So after messing around with the colors and stepping through the code a bit more, I've found that only the pause/play button disappears in addition to the toolbar going white. But even after disappearing, clicking where it should be still sends a signal to the VC. And trying to reset the toolbar background to dark gray doesn't help.

Comment: When stepping through the code, what is the contents of `items` before the last line? Is it as expected?

Comment: @Mundi yes, as far as I can tell, the `items` array contains all the correct UIBarButtonItems. There are 7 in all - flexible space, rewind, flexible space, play/pause, flexible space, fast forward, and flexible space. The rewind and fast forward items possess the correct actions and target, so I assume the rest of the array is good.

Comment: Hmm, the toolbar code look OK. You could try to send it a `setNeedsDisplay`. The problem is likely to be found elsewhere.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` didn't work :( thanks, I will try looking elsewhere

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently. What helped was setting `toolbar.Items` to an empty array before setting it again to your items.

My swift is very limited, so please excuse any compiler errors:

```
 items = self.bottomToolbar.items
 self.bottomToolbar.setItems:([], animated: false)
 items?[3] = newButton
 self.bottomToolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. Interestingly, setting the toolbar items to an empty array also causes it to go blank.